# Angular2 text-mask addons (createAutoCorrectedDatePipe used for Date of Birth)

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular2-directives

I used text-mask and text-mask addon and i used it for date of birth its not checking valid date when we enter and it is accepting future dates as well.. Please can any one help me..
My ts file,

```
 import createAutoCorrectedDatePipe from 'text-mask-addons/dist/createAutoCorrectedDatePipe';

export class HomeComponent {
   autoCorrectedDatePipe: any = createAutoCorrectedDatePipe('mm/dd/yyyy');
   mask: any = [/\d/, /\d/, '/', /\d/, /\d/, '/', /\d/, /\d/, /\d/, /\d/];
}
```

My template,

```
 <input [maxlength]="20" [textMask]="{mask: mask, keepCharPositions: true, pipe: autoCorrectedDatePipe}" [(ngModel)]="myModel" type="text" [formControl]="form.controls['dob']" name="dob" class="form-control">
```

Answer (score 1):

Mask is only for writing masked value. For testing if value is valid, you should use validator: https://angular.io/guide/form-validation

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by reactive form validation

in ts file:

```
 this.ocapForm = this.formBuilder.group({
        dob: ['', Validators.required]
    });
```

in html

```
 <div class="col-md-6 text-left pl-0">
   <input type="text" formControlName="dob" class="form__input--text">
 </div>
```

You can write you own validation also

in ts

```
withdrawalDate: ['', validateDate]
```

in the fuction you called in the validation

```
public validateDate(control: FormControl){
    const dob = control.value; // to geth the value of name
    const requiredValidation = Validators.required(control); // you can do inbuild validation here aswell
    if (!!requiredValidation) {  // to check validation
        return requiredValidation; // return the error as you needed
    } else if (dob) {     // making your custom check here
        return { dobError: true };
    }
    return null;
```

}